# Error occurred while installing hdf5

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, installation, hdf5

I have installed Intel C,C++ and fortran compiler and tried to install hdf5 on Ubuntu.

However I have stuck because of an error when I compiled by typing

```
make
```

Here is the error message that I got.

```
  CCLD     testhdf5
ld: warning: libimf.so, needed by ../src/.libs/libhdf5.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
ld: warning: libsvml.so, needed by ../src/.libs/libhdf5.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
ld: warning: libirng.so, needed by ../src/.libs/libhdf5.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
ld: warning: libintlc.so.5, needed by ../src/.libs/libhdf5.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
ld: .libs/testhdf5: hidden symbol `__intel_cpu_feature_indicator_x' in /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.0.098/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libirc.a(cpu_feature_disp.o) is referenced by DSO
ld: final link failed: Bad value
Makefile:1519: recipe for target 'testhdf5' failed
make[1]: *** [testhdf5] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Develop/Project/dep_src/hdf5-1.8.17/test'
Makefile:576: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

And here is configuration that I used.

```
CC=icc CXX=icpc F9X=ifort CFLAGS='-O3 -xHost' CXXFLAGS='-O3 -xHost' ./configure --with-zlib=/home/Develop/Project/dep_libs/zlib  --prefix=/home/Develop/Project/dep_libs/hdf5-1.8.17-intel64 --enable-hl --enable-cxx --enable-fortran
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem and then somehow solved it. It seems that they cannot find the relative files like `libirng.so`, so I add intel's include and lib dir to the flags:

```
CFLAGS=-O3 -xHost -ip -I/opt/intel/include/intel64
LDFLAGS=-L/opt/intel/lib/intel64
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/lib/intel64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I have no idea why this lib directory needs to be added to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, otherwise, it still died.